# How to read a file line using php in a javascript variable without the breakline character?

Tags: php, javascript, file

I have a txt file on the server which contains 10 lines of text. The text file is rewritten sometimes, and I get new lines using "\r\n". My problem shows when I want to load the lines in javascript variables. I do it like this, but this work only for numbers or for the last line of the file, because it`s not using the breakline tag: var x = '<?php echo $file[0]; ?>';
I`ve tried to alert(x) but it`s not working.... (working only if I read the last line)
Any idead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all! The I solved the problem with the help of artlung and Richard JP Le Guen:

```
var x = <?php rtrim($file[0]); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but you should be able to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) which will escape the data appropriately:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($file[0], JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
```

As others have said, you can `trim()` the data to remove trailing whitespace/line breaks. You should still use `json_encode()` in addition to this as otherwise it will still be possible to  break out of the javascript string (e.g. by sending a string with a quote in).

Comment: But json_encode() is not for outputting an entire array ? My problem is that I want to cut out that "\r\n" breakline tag from the end of the text, the breakline is invisible, but it affects the work of my script.

Comment: `json_encode()` can turn basically any PHP variable into a "JavaScript-safe" representation. It won't delete your newline, rather it will safely encode them. More info: http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: +1 much better than trying to work out JavaScript escaping yourself. Ideally, use the JSON_HEX_TAG flag to ensure that a `</script>` in the content doesn't cause the surrounding script block to end early.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/trim):

```
var x = '<?php echo trim($file[0]); ?>';
```

But if you read the [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), you could [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) it with `trim()` and then keep doing what you're doing:

```
$values = array_map("trim", file('input-file.txt'));
```

You might consider what happens if someone decides to include a single quote in the variable with this approach.

**EDIT:** Then you can add [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) as suggested in other answers:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($file[0]); ?>;
```

Comment: Perhaps `rtrim()` would be more appropriate?